# SQL query (Postgres) works normally, but not through ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I've got a SQL query in Postgres that works fine from a SQL console/tool, but not through Rails' ActiveRecord (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute/select_all). I've tried a bunch of stuff like escaping quotes, calling ActiveRecord::Base.quote/sanitize to no avail - ActiveRecord returns an empty set where I've verified a tuple gets returned with this query.

```
SELECT
      ... blah blah
      FROM
        ... joins joins joins
        inner join core.pat_assignments assignment on assignment.correspondent_alias_id = out_alias.id
        inner join core.pats patent on patent.id = assignment.pat_id and (select regexp_matches(patent.us_class_current, '(\w+)\/')) = '{D02}'
      where
        in_alias.id in (1987, 5004)
```

The funny thing is, it returns something if I take out the last inner join line, specifically the regex match. So there's something with:

```
(select regexp_matches(patent.us_class_current, '(\w+)\/')) = '{D02}'
```

that's making it throw up, but I just can't figure out why... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look in the development.log file; you'll see the actual SQL that results from the variants.  If it's not clear how they are different from that, post the differences (real ones, no "blah, blah" :-) and someone can probably help 'splain the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double that `\` to get `\w` down to the regex engine and then you have to double each of those to get them past Ruby's string literal handling. And you should use `E''` to avoid a warning. Also, you don't need that extra SELECT, you can compare the `regexp_matches` return value directly. So, something like this should work:

```
inner join ... and regexp_matches(patent.us_class_current, E'(\\\\w+)/') = array['D02']
```

There's no need to escape a slash in a PostgreSQL regex so I took that out too. Embedding a language (regex) inside a language (PostgreSQL's SQL) inside another language (Ruby) tends to get a bit messy when they all want to use the same escape character.

For example, in `psql` these things happen:

```
psql=> select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\w+)/');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
(0 rows)

psql=> select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\w+)/');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {D03}
(1 row)

psql=> select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\w+)/') = array['D03'];
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

And then from the Rails console:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\w+)/')})
   (0.5ms)  select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\w+)/')
 => [] 
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\w+)/')})
   (1.9ms)  select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\w+)/')
 => [] 
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\\\w+)/')})
   (0.4ms)  select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\w+)/')
 => [["{D03}"]] 
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\\\w+)/') = array['D03']})
   (1.4ms)  select regexp_matches('D03/pancakes', E'(\\w+)/') = array['D03']
 => [["t"]]
```